Evaluation of ifelse() vs if_else(), why is the true evaluation happening if the condition is not met?
Could someone shed some light on why with if_else, evaluation of the true statement appears to be happening even when the condition is not true?
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~record_id, ~date,
  "id_1", as.Date("2025-12-25"),
  "id_1", as.Date("2024-12-25"),
  "id_2", as.Date("2026-12-25"),
  "id_2", NA,
  "id_3", NA)

df %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>% 
  mutate(non_na = ifelse(any(!is.na(date)), # are there any dates for this individual
                         min(date, na.rm = T), # put the earliest non-na date in
                         NA_Date_))

df %>% 
  group_by(record_id) %>% 
  mutate(non_na = if_else(any(!is.na(date)), 
                          min(date, na.rm = T),
                          NA_Date_))

The use of if_else throws a warning:
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `non_na = if_else(any(!is.na(date)), min(date, na.rm = T),
  NA_Date_)`.
ℹ In group 3: `record_id = "id_3"`.

Which I understand, but the condition means this should never have been evaluated, right?
I know it is just a warning not an error, but it seems like unnecessary evaluation (extra overhead/processing that wasn't needed).
ifelse doesn't have this issue, though you need to add as.Date() to get the correct output.
Thanks!

Pretty sure if_else evaluates both the TRUE and FALSE outcome regardless of the input. I think this will show in this simple example: if_else(TRUE, TRUE, {falseeval <- 1; FALSE}); falseeval;

@thelatemail yes, I guess in hindsight this might not be a question with an actual answer per se :/ the "evaluated regardless" point (which I think I knew when asking) seems problematic as it 1) doubles the amount of computation being done, and 2) causes errors/warnings from things that do not need evaluation, but perhaps there is a nugget of wisdom I'm missing?

The upshot is probably that if_else is for returning a vector. Your operation is essentially returning a single value per group so if and else would be more fitting and would short-circuit evaulation.

if (any(!is.na(date))) min(date, na.rm = T) else NA

Agree with @thelatemail, you are misusing ifelse. if is a perfectly fine function that should be used here because it is (a) intended for this, (b) faster, (c) only evaluates one of the expressions.

Could someone please post a summary of these comments as an answer? (There's a deeper question about whether there would be an equivalent of ifelse/if_else that is more careful in evaluation, i.e. evaluating the test condition first and then evaluating only the required elements of the yes/no arguments ...)


...the condition means this should never have been evaluated, right?

Nope - if_else evaluates both the TRUE and FALSE outcome regardless of the input.
This will be evident in this simple example:
if_else(TRUE, TRUE, {falseeval <- 1; FALSE})
#[1] TRUE
falseeval
#[1] 1


I know it is just a warning not an error, but it seems like unnecessary evaluation (extra overhead/processing that wasn't needed).

The upshot is that if_else is for returning a vector. Your operation is essentially returning a single value per group so if and else would be more fitting and would short-circuit evaulation as intended:
df %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  mutate(non_na = if (any(!is.na(date))) min(date, na.rm = T) else NA)
## A tibble: 
## Groups:   record_id [3]
#  record_id date       non_na    
#  <chr>     <date>     <date>    
#1 id_1      2025-12-25 2024-12-25
#2 id_1      2024-12-25 2024-12-25
#3 id_2      2026-12-25 2026-12-25
#4 id_2      NA         2026-12-25
#5 id_3      NA         NA      

